# how to get the individual items in predict_proba python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the probability in the model but I want the results to be printed out as the probability of the second class only. ow should I do it?

```
prediction = model.predict_proba(input)
prediction = np.array(prediction)
prediction = prediction[-1]
```

The result show [0.66 0.33]

But I only want the 0.33.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Then the last line should be `prediction = prediction[-1][-1]` or `prediction = prediction[-1][1]`.

As @Tomerikoo made me notice, you need the second element (`...[1]`) which corresponds also to the last one `...[-1]`